# How to loop over a host group in ansible providing a dynamic value

Tags: ansible

I have the following inventory

```
group1:
  host001:
  host002:
group2:
  host101:
  host102:
```

Now I want to loop over either of the groups, controlled via a parameter e.g.

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    target: group1
- name: Do something for an inventory group
  include_tasks: sample-play.yml
  loop: "{{ groups['{{ target }}'] }}"
```

Is that even possible? if yes how? I tried

```
loop: "{{ groups['{{ target }}'] }}"
```

and

```
loop: "{{ groups.{{ target }} }}"
```

Both ending with the following error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected name or number. String: {{ groups.{{ target }} }}"}
```

What I want to achieve is to modify a local file and add an entry for each host in a group. Concretely I want to add a proxy entry for each host of a group to the ssh `config`-file.

Comment: Thanks, so removing the `'` and `{{`, `}}` helped ;-) If you answer the question, I would be glad to give you some points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix the syntax

```yaml
loop: "{{ groups[target] }}"
```

Expansion can't be nested `"{{  {{ }}  }}"`.

Comment: Thanks again, solution is basically simple, just didn't see

Answer (score 0):

By default Ansible forks the play for a given host group (controlled by `ansible.cfg`). Looks like you want to execute tasks sequentially as if iterating over the group.

There are many ways to control [playbook execution](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html).

You can use the `serial` keyword as below if you want run the tasks on hosts in your group sequentially:

```yaml
- hosts: group1
  serial: 1

  tasks:
  - name: Do something for an inventory group
    include_tasks: sample-play.yml
```

This will make Ansible run `sample-play.yml` for `host001` first, then rerun on `host002`

Comment: What I actually want is to modify a single file locally (on where I run ansible) an entry for each host in a group

Comment: Can you update your question with the entries you want, and in which file?